# How to disable on the Clearcase Server for RESERVED CHECKOUT within VOB?

Tags: clearcase

How to disable on the server side across VOB any form of RESERVED CHECKOUT for any element within CLEARCASE irrespective of CLIENT side SETUP configuration?

Comment: Because POST-OP Trigger already checkout RESERVED and then tries to UNRESERVE which might fail, is there any way I can use PRE-OP trigger which checks of RESERVE Option in the CHECKOUT and fails the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed in the "[About reserved and unreserved checkouts](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21135939#default)" page, you can make a trigger which would immediatly "unreserve" and reserved checkout:

UNIX and Linux:

> `cleartool mktrtype -element -all -post checkout -exec '/opt/rational/clearcase/bin/cleartool unreserve -nc $CLEARCASE_PN' <Tigger_Name>`

Microsoft Windows:

> `cleartool mktrtype -element -all -post checkout -exec "cleartool unreserve -nc \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\"" <Tigger_Name>`

The other approach (in [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013896826)) is a script which tests the environment variable "`CLEARCASE_RESERVED`". If this is `1`, then it's a reserved checkout and you can exit to prevent the checkout.

> A Perl Script example would be like this.

```perl
if ($ENV{CLEARCASE_RESERVED} == 1)
{
  print "A reserved checkout is not allowed. Please do an
  unreserved checkout.\n";
  exit 1;
}
```

Comment: Because POST-OP Trigger already checkout RESERVED and then tries to UNRESERVE which might fail, is there any way I can use PRE-OP trigger which checks of RESERVE Option in the CHECKOUT and fails the command?

Comment: @user3806728 as the same page mentions "The trigger will fail if the trigger is a "preop checkout" trigger. This is because the file is not checkedout first." So give it a try, it should not fail.